# State saving issues

Tags: reactjs, state, jsx

So in this code snippet i have a card that has 2 span elements, both spans take css values in the form of props, everything works fine for the most part, the main issue in here is that i want to maintain the state of each span seperate from the other so that when i start editing one span element and focusing on the other, the same css values dont apply to the other span element, but instead i want to load the span element's init state and apply seperate css values to each span when the the respective activetextarea is active

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

const Card = (props) => {


    // if active text area changes, save current state for loading again
    const [spanText, setSpanText] = useState("Type Here")
    const [spanText2, setSpanText2] = useState("Type Here")
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
    const [isHovered2, setIsHovered2] = useState(false);
    const [activeTextarea, setActiveTextarea] = useState(null);
    const [span1Styles, setSpan1Styles] = useState({
        color: "white",
        fontSize: "19px",
        fontFamily: props.font
    });
    const [span2Styles, setSpan2Styles] = useState({
        color: "white",
        fontSize: "19px",
        fontFamily: props.font
    });




    const handleSpan1Click = () => {
        setActiveTextarea(1);
    };

    const handleSpan2Click = () => {
        setActiveTextarea(2);
    };

    const handleMouseEnter = () => {
        setIsHovered(true);
        setIsHovered2(true)
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        if (spanText === "Type Here") {
            setIsHovered(false);
        }
        if (spanText2 === "Type Here") {
            setIsHovered2(false)
        }
    };

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSpanText(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleChange2 = (e) => {
        setSpanText2(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(activeTextarea, "el active rakam")
        if (activeTextarea === 1) {
            setSpan1Styles({
                color: props.color,
                fontSize: props.fontSize + 'px',
                fontFamily: props.font
            });
        }

        if (activeTextarea === 2) {
            setSpan2Styles({
                color: props.color,
                fontSize: props.fontSize + 'px',
                fontFamily: props.font
            });
        }


        console.log(span1Styles)
        console.log(span2Styles)
        console.log("aloo")
    }, [props, spanText, activeTextarea]);

    return (
        <>
            <div className='flex myDIV justify-center mt-10 w-[100%] md:w-[90%] self-start relative'>
                <div
                    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
                    onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
                    id="test"
                    onClick={props.handleEdit}
                    className="card parent parent-container test w-[100%]"
                    style={{
                        /*   backgroundImage: `url(${props.thumb.img})`, */
                        backgroundImage: "url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1684324500031-65fc8dcd4156?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80)",
                        backgroundSize: "cover", backgroundPosition: "center center", backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat", aspectRatio: "16/9"
                    }}>
                    <Draggable
                        enableUserSelectHack={false}
                        axis="both"
                        handle=".handle"
                        position={null}
                        scale={1}
                        bounds=".card"
                    >
                        <div className="handle w-max">
                            {isHovered && (
                                <span
                                    onClick={handleSpan1Click}
                                    onInput={handleChange}
                                    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                                    contentEditable
                                    suppressContentEditableWarning
                                    style={span1Styles}
                                    className={`bg-transparent text-[19px] text-white text-cairo outline-none hover:border whitespace-pre overflow-hidden resize-none`}
                                >
                                    {spanText}
                                </span>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </Draggable>

                    <Draggable
                        enableUserSelectHack={false}
                        axis="both"
                        handle=".handle"
                        position={null}
                        scale={1}
                        bounds=".card"
                    >
                        <div className="handle w-max">
                            {isHovered2 && (
                                <span
                                    onClick={handleSpan2Click}
                                    onInput={handleChange2}
                                    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                                    contentEditable
                                    suppressContentEditableWarning
                                    style={span2Styles}
                                    className={`bg-transparent text-[19px] text-white text-cairo outline-none hover:border whitespace-pre overflow-hidden resize-none`}
                                >
                                    {spanText2}
                                </span>
                            )}
                        </div>


                    </Draggable>


                </div>
            </div >
        </>
    )
}

export default Card
```

i have spent the last 3 days wrapping my head around the issue and trying different soultions, only for everything to fail, thanks for anyone that will help <3

Comment: Can you show what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using some kind of boolean map like

```js
const [activeTextarea, setActiveTextarea] = useState({span1: false, span2:false});

const handleSpan1Click = () => {
        setActiveTextarea({...activeTextarea, span1: true});
};

const handleSpan2Click = () => {
        setActiveTextarea({...activeTextarea, span2: true});
};
```